# Using DISTANCE function with parent field

Tags: apex

I tried doing this..

```
DISTANCE(Fire_Station__r.Location__c, GEOLOCATION(xx.xxxxx, xx.xxxxx)
```

but it's failing.

Can I compute distance with a parent location field?

Comment: What exception is thrown?

Answer (score 0):

This formula field on Contact object works fine where it is referring Account's Location field.

Moreover, `Distance` formula takes 3 arguments including unit, which is missing at your code.

```
DISTANCE( Account.Location__c, GEOLOCATION(37.775,-122.418), 'km')
```

Refer [DISTANCE](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions_a_h.htm&type=0&language=en_US)

Also, following SOQL query works well

```
SELECT Id, Name 
     FROM Contact
     WHERE DISTANCE(Account.Main_Office__c, GEOLOCATION(37.775,-122.418), 'km') > 20
```

Refer [Location and Distance Variables Allowed in SOQL and SOSL Queries in Apex - release notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer15/release-notes/rn_apex_soql_binding.htm)